# Handling token error in calculator program

Tags: parsing, haskell, token, calculator

I'm trying to handle token errors in the calculator programme I made with haskell, my code is as follows:

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Applicative

data MayError a = Value a | Error String

instance (Show a) => Show (MayError a) where
  show (Value x) = show x
  show (Error s) = "error: " ++ s

instance Functor MayError where
  fmap f (Value x) = Value (f x)
  fmap f (Error s) = Error s

instance Applicative MayError where
  pure x = Value x
  (Value f) <*> (Value x) = Value (f x)
  (Value f) <*> (Error s) = Error s
  (Error s) <*> _ = Error s

instance Monad MayError where
  return x = Value x
  (Value x) >>= f = f x
  (Error s) >>= f = Error s

{- tokenizer -}
data Token = Num Int | Add | Sub | Mul | Div | Exp | LPar | RPar deriving (Eq, Show)

tokens :: String -> MayError [Token]
tokens [] = []
tokens ('+':cs) = Add:(tokens cs)
tokens ('-':cs) = Sub:(tokens cs)
tokens ('*':cs) = Mul:(tokens cs)
tokens ('/':cs) = Div:(tokens cs)
tokens ('(':cs) = LPar:(tokens cs)
tokens (')':cs) = RPar:(tokens cs)
tokens ('^':cs) = Exp:(tokens cs)
tokens (c:cs) | isDigit c = let (ds,rs) = span isDigit (c:cs)
                            in Num(read ds):(tokens rs)
              | isSpace c = tokens cs
              | otherwise = Error "unknown token"

{- parser -}
data ParseTree = Number Int |
                 Plus ParseTree ParseTree |
                 Minus ParseTree ParseTree |
                 Times ParseTree ParseTree |
                 Divide ParseTree ParseTree |
                 Power ParseTree ParseTree
                 deriving Show

type Parser = [Token] -> MayError(ParseTree, [Token])

parseFactor::Parser
parseFactor (Num x:l) = return (Number x, l)
parseFactor (Add:l) = parseFactor l
parseFactor (Sub:l) = let (p1, l1) = parseFactor l in (Minus (Number 0) p1, l1)
parseFactor (LPar:l) = let (p1, RPar:l1) = parseExpr l in (p1, l1)
parseFactor _ = Error "parse error"

parseExponent::Parser
parseExponent l = nextExp $ parseFactor l
  where nextExp(p1, Exp:l1) = let (p2, l2) = parseFactor l1
                              in nextExp(Power p1 p2, l2)
        nextExp x = x

parseTerm::Parser
parseTerm l = nextFactor $ parseExponent l
  where nextFactor(p1, Mul:l1) = let (p2,l2) = parseExponent l1
                                 in nextFactor(Times p1 p2, l2)
        nextFactor(p1, Div:l1) = let (p2,l2) = parseExponent l1
                                 in nextFactor(Divide p1 p2, l2)
        nextFactor x = x

parseExpr::Parser
parseExpr l = nextTerm $ parseTerm l
  where nextTerm(p1, Add:l1) = let (p2,l2) = parseTerm l1
                               in nextTerm(Plus p1 p2, l2)
        nextTerm(p1, Sub:l1) = let (p2,l2) = parseTerm l1
                               in nextTerm(Minus p1 p2, l2)
        nextTerm x = x

{- evaluator -}
eval::ParseTree -> MayError Int
eval (Number x) = Value x
eval (Plus p1 p2) = do x <- eval p1
                       y <- eval p2
                       return (x+y)
eval (Minus p1 p2) = do x <- eval p1
                        y <- eval p2
                        return (x-y)
eval (Times p1 p2) = do x <- eval p1
                        y <- eval p2
                        return (x*y)
eval (Divide p1 p2) = do x <- eval p1
                         y <- eval p2
                         if y == 0 then Error "division by 0" 
                                   else return (x `div` y)
eval (Power p1 p2) = do x <- eval p1
                        y <- eval p2
                        if y < 0 then Error "cannot process negative exponents"
                                 else return (x^y)

parse :: [Token] ->  MayError ParseTree
parse ts = do (pt, rs) <- parseExpr ts
              if null rs then return pt else Error "extra token"                                                                                                                                         

{- main -}
main = do cs <- getContents
          putStr $ unlines $ map show $
            map (\s -> tokens s >>= parse >>= eval) $ lines cs
```

Everything works fine when I wasn't trying to parse errors, but now the error is as shown below:

```
calc_final2.hs:29:13: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError [Token]’
                  with actual type ‘[a1]’
    • In the expression: []
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens [] = []
   |
29 | tokens [] = []
   |             ^^

calc_final2.hs:30:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError [Token]’
                  with actual type ‘[Token]’
    • In the expression: Add : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('+' : cs) = Add : (tokens cs)
   |
30 | tokens ('+':cs) = Add:(tokens cs)
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:30:24: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Token]’
                  with actual type ‘MayError [Token]’
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(tokens cs)’
      In the expression: Add : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('+' : cs) = Add : (tokens cs)
   |
30 | tokens ('+':cs) = Add:(tokens cs)
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:31:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError [Token]’
                  with actual type ‘[Token]’
    • In the expression: Sub : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('-' : cs) = Sub : (tokens cs)
   |
31 | tokens ('-':cs) = Sub:(tokens cs)
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:31:24: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Token]’
                  with actual type ‘MayError [Token]’
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(tokens cs)’
      In the expression: Sub : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('-' : cs) = Sub : (tokens cs)
   |
31 | tokens ('-':cs) = Sub:(tokens cs)
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:32:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError [Token]’
                  with actual type ‘[Token]’
    • In the expression: Mul : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('*' : cs) = Mul : (tokens cs)
   |
32 | tokens ('*':cs) = Mul:(tokens cs)
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:32:24: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Token]’
                  with actual type ‘MayError [Token]’
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(tokens cs)’
      In the expression: Mul : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('*' : cs) = Mul : (tokens cs)
   |
32 | tokens ('*':cs) = Mul:(tokens cs)
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:33:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError [Token]’
                  with actual type ‘[Token]’
    • In the expression: Div : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('/' : cs) = Div : (tokens cs)
   |
33 | tokens ('/':cs) = Div:(tokens cs)
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:33:24: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Token]’
                  with actual type ‘MayError [Token]’
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(tokens cs)’
      In the expression: Div : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('/' : cs) = Div : (tokens cs)
   |
33 | tokens ('/':cs) = Div:(tokens cs)
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:34:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError [Token]’
                  with actual type ‘[Token]’
    • In the expression: LPar : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('(' : cs) = LPar : (tokens cs)
   |
34 | tokens ('(':cs) = LPar:(tokens cs)
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:34:25: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Token]’
                  with actual type ‘MayError [Token]’
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(tokens cs)’
      In the expression: LPar : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('(' : cs) = LPar : (tokens cs)
   |
34 | tokens ('(':cs) = LPar:(tokens cs)
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:35:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError [Token]’
                  with actual type ‘[Token]’
    • In the expression: RPar : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens (')' : cs) = RPar : (tokens cs)
   |
35 | tokens (')':cs) = RPar:(tokens cs)
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:35:25: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Token]’
                  with actual type ‘MayError [Token]’
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(tokens cs)’
      In the expression: RPar : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens (')' : cs) = RPar : (tokens cs)
   |
35 | tokens (')':cs) = RPar:(tokens cs)
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:36:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError [Token]’
                  with actual type ‘[Token]’
    • In the expression: Exp : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('^' : cs) = Exp : (tokens cs)
   |
36 | tokens ('^':cs) = Exp:(tokens cs)
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:36:24: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Token]’
                  with actual type ‘MayError [Token]’
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(tokens cs)’
      In the expression: Exp : (tokens cs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’: tokens ('^' : cs) = Exp : (tokens cs)
   |
36 | tokens ('^':cs) = Exp:(tokens cs)
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:38:32: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError [Token]’
                  with actual type ‘[Token]’
    • In the expression: Num (read ds) : (tokens rs)
      In the expression:
        let (ds, rs) = span isDigit (c : cs) in Num (read ds) : (tokens rs)
      In an equation for ‘tokens’:
          tokens (c : cs)
            | isDigit c
            = let (ds, rs) = span isDigit (c : cs)
              in Num (read ds) : (tokens rs)
            | isSpace c = tokens cs
            | otherwise = Error "unknown token"
   |
38 |                             in Num(read ds):(tokens rs)
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:38:46: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Token]’
                  with actual type ‘MayError [Token]’
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(tokens rs)’
      In the expression: Num (read ds) : (tokens rs)
      In the expression:
        let (ds, rs) = span isDigit (c : cs) in Num (read ds) : (tokens rs)
   |
38 |                             in Num(read ds):(tokens rs)
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:56:38: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, b)’
                  with actual type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the expression: parseFactor l
      In a pattern binding: (p1, l1) = parseFactor l
      In the expression:
        let (p1, l1) = parseFactor l in (Minus (Number 0) p1, l1)
    • Relevant bindings include
        p1 :: a (bound at calc_final2.hs:56:28)
        l1 :: b (bound at calc_final2.hs:56:32)
   |
56 | parseFactor (Sub:l) = let (p1, l1) = parseFactor l in (Minus (Number 0) p1, l1)
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:56:55: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
                  with actual type ‘(ParseTree, b0)’
    • In the expression: (Minus (Number 0) p1, l1)
      In the expression:
        let (p1, l1) = parseFactor l in (Minus (Number 0) p1, l1)
      In an equation for ‘parseFactor’:
          parseFactor (Sub : l)
            = let (p1, l1) = parseFactor l in (Minus (Number 0) p1, l1)
   |
56 | parseFactor (Sub:l) = let (p1, l1) = parseFactor l in (Minus (Number 0) p1, l1)
   |                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:57:44: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, [Token])’
                  with actual type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the expression: parseExpr l
      In a pattern binding: (p1, RPar : l1) = parseExpr l
      In the expression: let (p1, RPar : l1) = parseExpr l in (p1, l1)
    • Relevant bindings include p1 :: a (bound at calc_final2.hs:57:29)
   |
57 | parseFactor (LPar:l) = let (p1, RPar:l1) = parseExpr l in (p1, l1)
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:57:59: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
                  with actual type ‘(a0, [Token])’
    • In the expression: (p1, l1)
      In the expression: let (p1, RPar : l1) = parseExpr l in (p1, l1)
      In an equation for ‘parseFactor’:
          parseFactor (LPar : l)
            = let (p1, RPar : l1) = parseExpr l in (p1, l1)
   |
57 | parseFactor (LPar:l) = let (p1, RPar:l1) = parseExpr l in (p1, l1)
   |                                                           ^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:61:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
                  with actual type ‘(ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the expression: nextExp $ parseFactor l
      In an equation for ‘parseExponent’:
          parseExponent l
            = nextExp $ parseFactor l
            where
                nextExp (p1, Exp : l1) = let ... in nextExp (Power p1 p2, l2)
                nextExp x = x
   |
61 | parseExponent l = nextExp $ parseFactor l
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:61:29: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(ParseTree, [Token])’
                  with actual type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘parseFactor l’
      In the expression: nextExp $ parseFactor l
      In an equation for ‘parseExponent’:
          parseExponent l
            = nextExp $ parseFactor l
            where
                nextExp (p1, Exp : l1) = let ... in nextExp (Power p1 p2, l2)
                nextExp x = x
   |
61 | parseExponent l = nextExp $ parseFactor l
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:62:46: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, b)’
                  with actual type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the expression: parseFactor l1
      In a pattern binding: (p2, l2) = parseFactor l1
      In the expression:
        let (p2, l2) = parseFactor l1 in nextExp (Power p1 p2, l2)
    • Relevant bindings include
        p2 :: a (bound at calc_final2.hs:62:36)
        l2 :: b (bound at calc_final2.hs:62:40)
   |
62 |   where nextExp(p1, Exp:l1) = let (p2, l2) = parseFactor l1
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:67:15: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
                  with actual type ‘(ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the expression: nextFactor $ parseExponent l
      In an equation for ‘parseTerm’:
          parseTerm l
            = nextFactor $ parseExponent l
            where
                nextFactor (p1, Mul : l1) = let ... in nextFactor (Times p1 p2, l2)
                nextFactor (p1, Div : l1)
                  = let ... in nextFactor (Divide p1 p2, l2)
                nextFactor x = x
   |
67 | parseTerm l = nextFactor $ parseExponent l
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:67:28: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(ParseTree, [Token])’
                  with actual type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘parseExponent l’
      In the expression: nextFactor $ parseExponent l
      In an equation for ‘parseTerm’:
          parseTerm l
            = nextFactor $ parseExponent l
            where
                nextFactor (p1, Mul : l1) = let ... in nextFactor (Times p1 p2, l2)
                nextFactor (p1, Div : l1)
                  = let ... in nextFactor (Divide p1 p2, l2)
                nextFactor x = x
   |
67 | parseTerm l = nextFactor $ parseExponent l
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:68:48: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, b)’
                  with actual type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the expression: parseExponent l1
      In a pattern binding: (p2, l2) = parseExponent l1
      In the expression:
        let (p2, l2) = parseExponent l1 in nextFactor (Times p1 p2, l2)
    • Relevant bindings include
        p2 :: a (bound at calc_final2.hs:68:39)
        l2 :: b (bound at calc_final2.hs:68:42)
   |
68 |   where nextFactor(p1, Mul:l1) = let (p2,l2) = parseExponent l1
   |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:70:48: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, b)’
                  with actual type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the expression: parseExponent l1
      In a pattern binding: (p2, l2) = parseExponent l1
      In the expression:
        let (p2, l2) = parseExponent l1 in nextFactor (Divide p1 p2, l2)
    • Relevant bindings include
        p2 :: a (bound at calc_final2.hs:70:39)
        l2 :: b (bound at calc_final2.hs:70:42)
   |
70 |         nextFactor(p1, Div:l1) = let (p2,l2) = parseExponent l1
   |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:75:15: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
                  with actual type ‘(ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the expression: nextTerm $ parseTerm l
      In an equation for ‘parseExpr’:
          parseExpr l
            = nextTerm $ parseTerm l
            where
                nextTerm (p1, Add : l1) = let ... in nextTerm (Plus p1 p2, l2)
                nextTerm (p1, Sub : l1) = let ... in nextTerm (Minus p1 p2, l2)
                nextTerm x = x
   |
75 | parseExpr l = nextTerm $ parseTerm l
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:75:26: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(ParseTree, [Token])’
                  with actual type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘parseTerm l’
      In the expression: nextTerm $ parseTerm l
      In an equation for ‘parseExpr’:
          parseExpr l
            = nextTerm $ parseTerm l
            where
                nextTerm (p1, Add : l1) = let ... in nextTerm (Plus p1 p2, l2)
                nextTerm (p1, Sub : l1) = let ... in nextTerm (Minus p1 p2, l2)
                nextTerm x = x
   |
75 | parseExpr l = nextTerm $ parseTerm l
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:76:46: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, b)’
                  with actual type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the expression: parseTerm l1
      In a pattern binding: (p2, l2) = parseTerm l1
      In the expression:
        let (p2, l2) = parseTerm l1 in nextTerm (Plus p1 p2, l2)
    • Relevant bindings include
        p2 :: a (bound at calc_final2.hs:76:37)
        l2 :: b (bound at calc_final2.hs:76:40)
   |
76 |   where nextTerm(p1, Add:l1) = let (p2,l2) = parseTerm l1
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^

calc_final2.hs:78:46: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, b)’
                  with actual type ‘MayError (ParseTree, [Token])’
    • In the expression: parseTerm l1
      In a pattern binding: (p2, l2) = parseTerm l1
      In the expression:
        let (p2, l2) = parseTerm l1 in nextTerm (Minus p1 p2, l2)
    • Relevant bindings include
        p2 :: a (bound at calc_final2.hs:78:37)
        l2 :: b (bound at calc_final2.hs:78:40)
   |
78 |         nextTerm(p1, Sub:l1) = let (p2,l2) = parseTerm l1
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What I'm trying to do exactly is to have my programme show "unknown token" when some invalid token is inputted.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since the return type of `tokens` is `MayError [Token]`, you need to wrap the items in a `Value`, for items where we recurse, we can perform an `fmap` to prepend to the list wrapped in the `Value`:

```
tokens :: String -> MayError [Token]
tokens [] = Value []
tokens ('+':cs) = (Add:) <$> tokens cs
tokens ('-':cs) = (Sub:) <$> tokens cs
tokens ('*':cs) = (Mul:) <$> tokens cs
tokens ('/':cs) = (Div:) <$> tokens cs
tokens ('(':cs) = (LPar:) <$>  tokens cs
tokens (')':cs) = (RPar:) <$>  tokens cs
tokens ('^':cs) = (Exp:) <$>  tokens cs
tokens (c:cs) | isDigit c = let (ds,rs) = span isDigit (c:cs)
                            in (Num (read ds):) <$> tokens rs
              | isSpace c = tokens cs
              | otherwise = Error "unknown token"
```

Other functions have the same problem: you should wrap values in a `Value` data constructor, or unwrap these if you are processing a `MayError` value.